Django Token authentication failure: Authentication credentials were not provided
I am working on the user logic of my Django project. Despite the fact that logout (using session cookie authentication) works perfectly fine in the browser, it is not working during testing for some reason. It appears as if the cookie from the login response isn't being correctly saved for the subsequent request. Here are the relevant excerpts from my project code:
views.py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db.models.manager import BaseManager
from rest_framework import generics, status, permissions, serializers
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

# from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
# from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

from apps.users.models import User
from apps.users.serializers import (
    UserSerializer,
    UserLoginSerializer,
)


class UserLoginView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class: type = UserLoginSerializer

    def get_object(self) -> AbstractBaseUser:
        """Overwrite method to get the authenticated user object"""
        try:
            session_key: str = self.request.COOKIES.get("session")
            user: AbstractBaseUser = Token.objects.get(key=session_key).user
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            user = None
        return user

    def post(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        response: Response
        user: AbstractBaseUser

        try:
            # parse data
            data: dict = {
                k: v[0] if type(v) is list and len(v) == 1 else v
                for k, v in dict(request.data).items()
            }
            # Verify the absence of session token
            serializer: serializers.Serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
            user = self.get_object()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError("Already logged in.")

            # Run serializer validations
            user = serializer.is_valid()
            if not user:
                raise ValidationError("Unable to log in with provided credentials.")

            # Create response content (in this case, just a confirmation message)
            response_content: dict[str, str] = {
                "detail": "Login successful",
            }
            # Create response object
            response = Response(data=response_content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            # Aggregate cookie to the response
            token: Token
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.validated_data)
            response.set_cookie(
                key="session",
                value=token.key,
                secure=True,
                httponly=True,
                samesite="lax",
            )

        except ValidationError as error:
            response = Response(
                {"detail": error.message},
                status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            )

        return response


class UserLogoutView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self) -> serializers.Serializer:
        return serializers.Serializer  # Return basic Serializer class

    def delete(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        response: Response
        try:
            session_key: str = request.COOKIES.get("session")
            token: Token = Token.objects.get(key=session_key)
            response = Response(
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                data={"detail": "Logout successful"},
            )
            response.delete_cookie(key="session")
            token.delete()

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            response = Response(
                {"error": "Session cookie not found"},
                status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            )
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            response = Response(
                {"detail": str(error)},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        return response

tests_views.py
class TestLogoutViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client = Client()
        self.data: dict[str, str] = {
            "username": "testuser",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "password": "Password1",
        }
        self.logout_url: str = reverse("user_logout")
        self.login_url: str = reverse("user_login")

        self.client.post(
            reverse("user_register"),
            json.dumps(self.data),
            content_type="application/json",
        )
        self.data.pop("email")

    def test_logout_view_correct_DELETE(self) -> None:

        # Log in first
        response: HttpResponse = self.client.post(
            self.login_url,
            json.dumps(self.data),
            content_type="application/json",
        )

        print()
        print(response.status_code, self.client.cookies)
        print(self.client.get("").wsgi_request.user)
        print()

        # Send the DELETE request
        response: HttpResponse = self.client.delete(self.logout_url)

        # Check if the response is 200
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            200,
            msg=(
                f"Response is {response.status_code}, expected 200. ",
                f"Response content: {response.content}",
            ),
        )

        # Check if the cookie is deleted
        self.assertFalse(
            "session" in self.client.cookies, msg="Cookie should be deleted"
        )

settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK: dict[str, str] = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
}

Output:
200 Set-Cookie: session=5875a98d252d48a019226a342fb09cb785271a32; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=lax; Secure
AnonymousUser
======================================================================
FAIL: test_logout_view_correct_DELETE (users.test_views.TestLogoutViews)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\user\repositories\flicks-and-picks\src\backend\apps\users\test_views.py", line 518, in test_logout_view_correct_DELETE
    self.assertEqual(
AssertionError: 401 != 200 : ('Response is 401, expected 200. ', 'Response content: b\'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}\'')


Update
By using this independent program to test the requests, I discovered that adding a header with an authorization field allows me to avoid the ‘Authentication credentials were not provided’ message. Despite this, I still don’t know the proper value to set in that field.
import os
import json
import requests

client = requests.session()
login_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/"
logout_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/logout/"
login_data: dict[str, str] = {"username": "test1", "password": "Password1"}

print()
response: requests.Response = client.post(login_url, json=login_data)
print(response.status_code, response.json()["detail"])
print()
print(client.cookies)

# Save the session cookie
cookies = response.cookies
session_cookie = response.cookies['session']
headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {session_cookie}'}

print()
response: requests.Response = client.delete(logout_url, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code, response.json()["detail"])

print()
response: requests.Response = client.delete(logout_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code, response.json()["detail"])

Output
200 Login successful

<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session=734df1e09726dd888a90ef25fc5b6f15151d8125 for 127.0.0.1/>]>

401 Authentication credentials were not provided.

401 Token matching query does not exist.


Can you first try to check if the user is authenticated, add these lines after login and before delete operations -
 response = self.client.get('')
user = response.wsgi_request.user.

Add the print statement to check for user this would let you access the user from request object.

It does. When I print the user I see: AnonymousUser

Please provide a [mre], to start with include your login view. Also try to demonstrate why you believe the token object should exist in your database.

You're not using Django's authentication system, hence the permissions.IsAuthenticated permission won't work for you...

True. Still doesnt work without it @AbdulAzizBarkat

Well without it the default permission classes specified in the settings would be used. Anyway, you seem to be trying to reinvent the wheel. Django and by extension Django Rest Framework has a pretty solid auth system, try to use them and work with them instead of reinventing it yourself.

The thing is that it works fine when I use it from the browser. I dont understand why doesnt it work when using independent requests. It must be something with the way cookies are send in the requests.
